# Laravel 5.2 Nested Eloquent relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a User which is of type Player and has several Equipments

I want to request a piece of Equipment and see if the User is it's owner before returning it to the user. If they do not own it they will get an unauthorized response

Here are the relationships I have for the models:

App\User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'user';

    public function player()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Player::class);
    }
}
```

App\Player.php

```
class Player extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'player';

    public function equipment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Equipment::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

App\Equipment.php

```
class Equipment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'equipement';

    public function player()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Player::class);
    }
}
```

EquipmentController.php

With my attempt which is working... just very ugly.

```
class EquipmentController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $equipment = Equipment::find($id);

        if ( ! $equipment ) {
            return 'Equipment does not exist');
        }

       // my attempt
        $test = Equipment::with('player.user')->findOrFail($id);

        if ($test->toArray()['player']['user']['id'] != Auth::user()->id){
            return 'Unauthorized';
        }
        //

        return $equipment;
    }
}
```

Is there a neater way to do this?

I want something readable in the controller like:

```
if(!$equipment->ownedBy(Auth::user())){
    return 'Unauthorized';
}
```

Or something similarly as readable.

And once the relationship is found, I'm not sure where the logic should be placed. Should it be in the Equipment model?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Equipment` model:

```
public function authorized()
{
   return ($this->player->user->id == auth()->user()->id())
}
```

Then from your controller, try:

```
$equipment->authorized() //returns true or false
```

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. Just another query, does it take away from the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) of the Equipment model? Should it instead, be put in an Equipment [Policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#policies) class and use the Gate class to authorize it in the controller?

Comment: There are multiple ways to go about it. This is just one way. In this way, you can use this function anywhere in your app.. Even in blade view.